# Strange value from bottomLayoutGuide

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

My view has a conditional by which it may or may not show toolbar at the bottom depending on whether user is creating new or viewing existing object. I am trying to use autolayout to move a button up or down consistently based on the appearance/disappearance of that toolbar.

I had problems with this, which seemed straight forward and simple.

```
[self.doneButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.doneButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];
```

I tried this alternative, cut and pasted right out of the Apple docs UIViewController Class Reference

```
UIButton *button = self.doneButton;
[button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
id bottomGuide = self.bottomLayoutGuide;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings (button, bottomGuide);
[self.view addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:[button]-20-[bottomGuide]"
                                         options: 0
                                         metrics: nil
                                           views: viewsDictionary]
 ];
[self.view layoutSubviews]; // You must call this method here or the system raises an exception
```

Either way, same problem. The button shows correctly, 20px from bottom, when there is no toolbar. It lands way higher, somewhere over 100px  when there is a toolbar showing.

So I added a NSLog to see the bottomLayoutGuide properties.

```
CGFloat bar = self.bottomLayoutGuide.length;
NSLog(@"bottom bar is %f",bar);
```

And this after layout

```
NSLog(@"button height is %f",self.view.bounds.size.height - self.doneButton.frame.origin.y);
```

Resulting in this from console

```
[Line 114] bottom bar is 93.000000
[Line 126] button height is 143.000000
```

Where is the 93 coming from? If I just put a standard constraint of 20 from bottom, the button gets hidden behind the toolbar. If `bottomLayoutGuide` returned the expected result, would be peachy.

Some other things I have tried include moving these methods to various other events such as `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. No improvement. I suppose I could just hard code the height of the toolbar but that makes no sense given the intent of `autolayout` and the layout guides.